# align local Y to be parallel with global Y during or after slerp

Tags: javascript, quaternion, three.js

I am using the following function to have a globe rotate a point on its surface to face the global Z toward the camera. This works fine, but after each rotation  the Y axis seen as a green line is not vertically aligned.

I believe this is how slerp between two unit vectors works, it takes the shortest path.

I would like to know how can I achieve this rotation whilst getting the globe to rotate itself so that Y is at least parallel to the global Y?

```
        function rotateToHub(continent){
            var speed = 2000;
            var z = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

            point = continent.position.clone().normalize();

            var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
            q.setFromUnitVectors(point, z);

            var duration = {t: 0};
            var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(duration)
                .to({t: 1}, speed)
                .onStart(function(){
                    slerp = true;
                })
                .onUpdate(function(){
                    earthContainer.quaternion.slerp(q, this.t);
                })
                .onComplete(function(){
                    slerp = false;
                    update();
                })
                .start();
        }
```

[image: globe]

Comment: Do not cross-post between SE sites.

Comment: I will delete from SO and keep the question here

Comment: Well, I don't know about THREE js but I think you are rotating target vector to Z (0,0,1) that making it like this. Just my guess, what would happen if you try `q.setFromUnitVectors(point, new THREE.Vector3(0, point.y, 1));` and sorry in advance if I did any syntax or spelling mistake

Comment: @HamzaHasan thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that moves my point away from centring on the Z and goes further to the Y axis up the globe.

Comment: I think both cases would be applicable at the same time. Either you will get your desired point at exact front and aligned to Z axis, or freeze the Y axis, I don't think both can be true at a time. What you say?

Comment: I don't actually want the Y to be the same as global Y as that will move my position from Z, I just want to rotate so that the Y is vertical, even if its half way between the current Z and global Y does this make sense?

Comment: Now I understand, I did some research, one good solution is `earthContainer.LookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0));` or something like this. Play around with LookAt, you will get what you want, I am pretty sure :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33226/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-neil).